# how to stop aws codepipeline deploy stage

Tags: aws-code-deploy, aws-codepipeline, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I created a continuous integration and continuous deployment pipeline with AWS codepipeline having 4 stages (Source, build, approval and deploy). It deploys to elastic beanstalk. however, the deploy stage keeps executing even after my application is now up and working fine. how do i tell codepipeline deploy stage that the deployment is successful?

Answer (score 1):

do you have new commits in the Source action? Usually, the deploy stage will be executed if you have new commits, which will trigger the source action, then build, then approval and then deploy. However, you could manually disable the deployment by clicking the transition between approval stage and deploy stage.

Or if the action keeps in progress state, this might help: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/troubleshooting.html#troubleshooting-aeb2

Cheers!